# Ubuntu can't connect to Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

can u please help me to config my ubuntu...
I can't connect just to one wifi on my job.
My phone and windowns computer are connecting correctly.
But Ubuntu 23.10 and 22.04 can't connect and asking to enter wifi password all time.

Please ask all additional information which you need.

P.S.
Wired connection is all right.

'''
**$ sudo iptables -L**

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere '''

'''$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network
описание: Беспроводной интерфейс
продукт: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
производитель: Intel Corporation
физический ID: 14.3
сведения о шине: pci@0000:00:14.3
логическое имя: wlp0s20f3
версия: 20
серийный №: 3c:e9:f7:c9:2a:93
разрядность: 64 bits
частота: 33MHz
возможности: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
конфигурация: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.5.0-10-generic firmware=77.2df8986f.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-77.u latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
ресурсы: iomemory:600-5ff IRQ:16 память:601d1bc000-601d1bffff
*-network
описание: Ethernet interface
физический ID: d
сведения о шине: usb@3:3.3
логическое имя: enx00e04c360c4d
серийный №: 00:e0:4c:36:0c:4d
размер: 100Mbit/s
capacity: 100Mbit/s
возможности: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
конфигурация: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.13 duplex=full ip=10.3.22.139 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
'''

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted docker network that was used local network (192.168.0.0) and add

> options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

to /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf

Comment: Try changing it to 8 instead of 1 and see if it is better